# How to keep Backbone events working with $el.html() method?

Tags: events, backbone.js, append

I'm writing a `Backbone App` where I'm trying to render a result list retrieved when I write on an `input` field.

This is basically my app

```
var Dropdown = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Templates:{}
}

Dropdown.Models.Product = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: dropdown.product.defaults || {},
    initialize:function () {
        console.log('Dropdown.Models.Product > initialize');
    }
});

Dropdown.Collections.Products = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Dropdown.Models.Product,
    initialize:function () {
        console.log('Dropdown.Collections.Products > initialize');

    }
});

Dropdown.Views.App = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize:function () {
        console.log('Dropdown.Views.App > initialize');
        this.subView = {
            Product : new Dropdown.Views.Product({
                collection : new Dropdown.Collections.Products()
            })
        }
    },
    render:function (options, term) {
        console.log('Dropdown.Views.App > render');
        var defaults = {
            where:false,
            products:{
                id:"product-results"
            }
        }
        var settings = $.extend(true, defaults, options);
        this.$el.html(this.subView.Product.render(settings.products.view, term).$el);
        // this.delegateEvents();
    }
});

Dropdown.Views.Product = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize:function () {
        console.log('Dropdown.Views.Product > initialize');
    },
    events: {
        "click .close": "closeResults",
    },
    closeResults:function (event) {
        console.log('Dropdown.Views.Product > closeResults');
        var view = this;
        this.$el.animate({height:0}, 500, function () {
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
            view.$el.hide();
        });
    },
    render:function (view, term) {
        this.$el.show();
        console.log('Dropdown.Views.Product > render');
        var data = (this.collection || this.model).toJSON();
        var template = Handlebars.compile($(this.template).html());
        this.$el.html(template({view:view, results:data}));
        this.delegateEvents(this.events); // to assign events if I'm using $el.html(...)
        return this;
    }
});
```

The app works, but I lost events after the second `render` method is called, probably because of the `.html()` method is called.

First callback:

```
 ---------------------
| app widget          |
 ---------------------
| result 1            |
| result 2            |
 ---------------------
|               close | <= event closeResults works
 ---------------------
```

Second callback:

```
 ---------------------
| app widget          |
 ---------------------
| result 1            |
| result 2            |
| result 3            |
 ---------------------
|               close | <= event closeResults lost
 ---------------------
```

If I try to change my app's method render to this:

```
render:function (view, term) {
    this.$el.show();
    console.log('render');
    var data = this.collection.toJSON() || this.model.toJSON();
    var template = Handlebars.compile($(this.template).html());
    // CHANGED this.$el.html to this.$el.append
    this.$el.append(template({view:view, results:data}));
    return this;
}
```

The events work always, but I accumulate server responses into the app's html, so this is the result:

First callback:

```
 ---------------------
| app widget          |
 ---------------------
| result 1            |
| result 2            |
 ---------------------
|               close | <= event closeResults works
 ---------------------
```

Second callback:

```
 ---------------------
| app widget          |
 ---------------------
| result 1            |
| result 2            |
 ---------------------
|               close | <= event closeResults works
 ---------------------
| app widget          | <= appended content, it doesn't replace previous result
 ---------------------
| result 1            |
| result 2            |
| result 3            |
 ---------------------
|               close | <= event closeResults works
 ---------------------
```

Basically with append I keep the events working but I don't replace the contents, how should I keep events working with `html` method?

Should I keep using `append` and prevent the duplicates in some way I missing?

Comment: As an aside, are you sure you don't mean `(this.collection || this.model).toJSON()` where you say `this.collection.toJSON() || this.model.toJSON()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my problem by changing the `.html` methods with `.append` in this way:

```
Dropdown.Views.App = Backbone.View.extend({
render:function (options, term) {
    console.log('Dropdown.Views.App > render');
    var defaults = {
        where:false,
        products:{
            id:"product-results"
        }
    }
    var settings = $.extend(true, defaults, options);
    // NO MORE THIS this.$el.html(this.subView.Product.render(settings.products.view, term).$el);
    this.subView.Product.delegateEvents();
    this.$el.empty();
    this.$el.append(this.subView.Product.render(settings.products.view, term).$el);
}
});
Dropdown.Views.Product = Backbone.View.extend({ 
// ...
render:function (view, term) {
    this.$el.show();
    console.log('Dropdown.Views.Product > render');
    var data = (this.collection || this.model).toJSON();
    var template = Handlebars.compile($(this.template).html());
    // NO MORE THIS this.$el.html(template({view:view, results:data}));
    this.$el.empty();
    this.delegateEvents(this.events);
    this.$el.append(template({view:view, results:data}));
    // to assign events if I'm using $el.html(...)
    return this;
}
});
```

In this way, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can add [delegateEvents](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) to your render.

```
render:function (view, term) {
    this.$el.show();
    console.log('render');
    var data = this.collection.toJSON() || this.model.toJSON();
    var template = Handlebars.compile($(this.template).html());
    this.$el.html(template({view:view, results:data}));
    this.delegateEvents();
    return this;
}
```

This will rebind the all the events in the views events hash to your el.

Comment: I've tried this but it still not working, maybe because I'm using this also as subview? I delegateEvent of the subview, not it's parent which is without events. It shouldn't be a problem because it works the first callback, what do you think?

Comment: I've updated to the full app structure, before now I thought the using of subview wasn't the problem but now I have doubts :)